# Observer and callback not triggered for accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, observer-pattern, nested-attributes

I have a models Topic and Post. Topic has_many :posts.

In Topic model I have also accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts,

Seems that neither observer nor callback is not triggered for Post model when updating Topic with some params for Post. Is it a bug or feature ?

Comment: did you enable your observer in `config/application.rb`? you must restart server then.

Comment: sure, I've used that observer before, for regular model updates, not through nested attributes

Comment: you should post you observer code as well.

Comment: it won't change anything, because observer is not called at all for that case. I've double checked with empty observer, just with some debug message.

Comment: are you sure you have :posts_attributes in your attr_accessible in the Topic model?

Comment: I have tried to reproduce your bug by using a "before_update" trigger in the nested model and it was called. Maybe you did something wrong...

Comment: Try firing up rails console and save or make an update to a Post. Did the observer run?

Comment: Mmmm... You are right, same issue here. Feature or Bug? I would have expected the callback to be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by *"when updating Topic with some params for Post"*, but `Post` callbacks will only run when you're updating a post object.

ie this will trigger callbacks:

```
@post.update_attributes(:topics_attributes => [...])
```

... but this won't:

```
@topic.update_attributes(:post_id => 123, ...)
```

If you want to trigger a `Post` `after_update` callback when a topic is updated you could do this:

```
# topic.rb
after_update :touch_post
private
def touch_post
  post.touch
end
```

Observer code will behave similarly to callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

When you run an update_attributes method, on a nested resource or not, the resource is saved only **if it has been changed** and if it pass through the validations : If not, the resource is not saved and the after_update is not triggered.